# Image Convolution with Mirror Boundary Condition

Tags: image-processing, filtering, convolution

Just a simple question related to image convolution boundary conditions. As every knows, there are several types of image convolution boundaries, among which symmetric condition is widely accepted. My question is: where do we put the “mirror” when performing convolution? More specifically, I give the following example:

Image matrix is [1 2 3], and the kernel is [ 1 1 1 1 1]. Then the mirrored image with regard to this kernel should be [ **3  2** 1 2 3 **2 3**] or [ **2 1** 1 2 3 **3 2**]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each edge needs to be mirrored independently. Your second example is the correct one.